# Cannot access multidimensional array in Swift

Tags: swift

I created a multidimensional array, but when I try to access it in `viewDidLoad` the application crashes. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

I also tried to define my array as `var data: KeyLabelType[][]`, but that didn't help either.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: Array<Array<KeyLabelType>> = []

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)  {

        let array1: KeyLabelType[] = [...]
        let array2: KeyLabelType[] = [...]
        let array3: KeyLabelType[] = [...]

        self.data = [array1, array2, array3]

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundle)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()  {

        let count = self.data.count // Application crashes here
    }
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

I declared `KeyLabelType` as

```
enum KeyLabelType: Character {
    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
    case c = "c"
}
```

EDIT: 
I filed a bug report with Apple (17340589)

Comment: How is your `KeyLabelType` class declared? I just tested your code in both playground and an app and it is working. I declared it as `class KeyLabelType {}`.

Comment: I declared `KeyLabelType` as an `enum`. I there something I'm missing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. This is just a guess, but might it be that you are running this code too early and that it all needs to happen in or after viewDidLoad?

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow I also tried putting everything in `viewDidLoad`, but I'm still getting the same error. I set `self.data=[]` in the initializer and then populated `data` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: If you place your code in a separate class and then create an instance of that class in viewDidLoad it runs fine. In addition, if you create an Int array that works as expected inside the ViewController code following your current process. I can only think therefore that it doesn't work because of the complexity of the array or the enum creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, please report it at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com). It is some how related to subclassing NSObject in swift.

```
import Foundation

enum KeyLabelType: Character {
    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
    case c = "c"
}

class MyClass: NSObject /* Removing NSObject here will fix the crash */ {
    var myData: Array<Array<KeyLabelType>>

    init() {
        let array1: Array<KeyLabelType> = [.a, .b]
        let array2: Array<KeyLabelType> = [.b]
        let array3: Array<KeyLabelType> = [.c]

        self.myData = [array1, array2, array3]
    }
}

var myObject = MyClass()
myObject.myData //Crash here, if subclassing NSObject. No crash if NSObject is removed
```

If you could rewrite your code to use NSObject subclasses all the way it might also work as a workaround

```
import Foundation

class KeyLabelType: NSObject {
    let value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

}

class MyClass: NSObject {
    var myData: NSArray

    init() {
        var item = KeyLabelType(1)
        var array1: NSArray = [KeyLabelType(1), KeyLabelType(2)]
        var array2: NSArray = [KeyLabelType(1), KeyLabelType(2)]
        self.myData = [array1, array2]
    }
}

var myObject = MyClass()
myObject.myData.count
```

Comment: This doesn't help you of course as you can't remove the dependency on UIViewController

Comment: Thank you. I will report it.